# accessing class properties and methods with a string representation of the property name

Tags: c#

I have a class which has a bunch of collections

```
Class MyInfoClass
{

Queue<float> firstQ = new Queue<float>();
Queue<float> secondQ = new Queue<float>();
Queue<float> thirdQ = new Queue<float>();
Queue<float> fourthQ = new Queue<float>();
Queue<float> fifthQ = new Queue<float>();

}
```

And another which has a string representation of the names of those collections

```
class myParamClass
{
 internal static string[] Chain =
        {
            "firstQ", 
            "secondQ",
            "thirdQ", 
            "fourthQ",
            "fifthQ"
        }           
}
```

I want to access the collections using the string representations

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyInfoClass myInfoChain = new MyInfoClass();

            float i = 0;

            //attempt to set 
            foreach (string qName in MyParamClass.Chain)
            {
                i++;
                myInfoChain.GetType().GetProperty(qName).SetValue(myInfoChain,i);
            }
            //attempt to get
            foreach (string qName in MyParamClass.Chain)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(myInfoChain.GetType().GetProperty(qName).GetValue(myInfoChain,null));
            }

        }
    }
```

I'm trying to use reflection but keep getting null object exceptions, but don't really care how I achieve this. I tried using an enum but hat was over complicating things, I've tried exposing the fields as properties and invoking the get set methods. I'm going round and round like a hamster.

Specifically I need to know how to access the collections as above, but in general how to I access the members (properties/field/method) of a class using a string of the (property/field/method) name  would be very useful?

What I have read keeps pointing to something like 
`var letMeIn =  typeof (MyInfoClass).GetProperty("_firstQ").GetValue(myInfoChain,null);` ????

but GetProperty("_firstQ") is null no matter what I do.

### Any help is appreciated.

Resolved as follows

> With respect to reflection exposing the queues as properties and using
>   this was a good solution,

```
   var letMeIn =  typeof (MyInfoClass).GetProperty("FirstQ")
                      .GetValue(myInfoChain,null);
```

> ```
> ... but I never managed to get the matching .SetValue() method working.
>
>
> What worked really well was the array of Queues
> ```

```
class MyInfoClass
{
    private Queue<float> _firstQ = new Queue<float>();
    private Queue<float> _secondQ = new Queue<float>();
    private Queue<float> _thirdQ = new Queue<float>();
    private Queue<float> _fourthQ = new Queue<float>();
    private Queue<float> _fifthQ = new Queue<float>();

    public Queue<float>[] MyQueues
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] { _firstQ, _secondQ, _thirdQ, _fourthQ, _fifthQ };
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> Which allowed me to iterate the collections byte index, and also to
> ```
>
> leverage LINQ in recusive loops (my core objective) as shown below
>   .

```
    class Program
    {

        static List<double> SeperateWorkMethod(List<double> d, float val)
        {
            //stuff/work on d, List<double>
            return d;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyInfoClass myInfoChain = new MyInfoClass();
            float x = 0;

            List<double> temp = new List<double>();

            foreach (Queue<float> t in myInfoChain.MyQueues)
            {
                x = x + 123;
                t.Enqueue(x);
                temp.Add(t.Average());
                temp.AddRange(t.Select(subType => subType.customField));
            }

            for (int index = 0; index < myInfoChain.MyQueues.Length; index++)
            {
                myInfoChain.MyQueues[index].Aggregate(temp, SeperateWorkMethod);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> I still feel like I should use an enum here somewhere, but the puzzle
>   is solved for now.   Many thanks to all.

Comment: Please don't add a resolution as part of the question.  If you found a good solution that you would like to post for others who may read your question, post it as another answer.  (It's okay to post an answer to your own question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but GetProperty("_firstQ") is null no matter what I do.

That's because you don't have a property `_firstQ`. Add one... (in addition to your fields)

```
public Queue<float> _firstQ { get { return firstQ; } }
```

and your code example above should work.

Note, though, that in C# properties usually start with an upper-case letter, so

```
public Queue<float> FirstQ { get { return firstQ; } }
```

would be more idiomatic.

---

In fact, if all you need to do is access the n-th queue dynamically, you don't need reflection at all:

```
public Queue<float>[] MyQueues
{ 
    get 
    {
        return new[] { firstQ, secondQ, thirdQ, fourthQ, fifthQ };
    }
}
```

and you can just access the n-th queue as `myInfoChain.MyQueues[n]`... no reflection needed.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed, Occams razor :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have properties, you have fields. So you need `GetField` method instead.Also the fields are private, you need to specify `BindingFlags.NonPublic` flag:

```
myInfoChain.GetType()
.GetField(qName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
.SetValue(myInfoChain,i);
```

Comment: I found it quite difficult to use .GetField; luckily I dont actually need to use reflection, which I had suspected. But thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your queues are fields, not properties.  Try defining them as

```
FirstQ { get; set; }
```

and assigning the queue in the constructor.  Then GetProperty("FirstQ") should get you what you need.